# in wiki about representing 0.1 in float point

Tags: floating-point

Inside a article at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), it said use `e = −4; s = 110011001100110011001101` to represent 0.1, where s is the significand and e is the exponent.
I guess the base of exponent is 2 and the result is 110011001100110011001101*(2^-4).

Obviously,it's a very huge number,far away from 0.1. What does the wikipedia article mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The significand is of the form `a.bcdefeg...`.

Your value is 1.1001100... * (2^-4).